# Curing spacetime singularities by a higher-curvature gravitational Lagrangian

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, black-holes, string-theory, singularities

It is well known that the self-energy of a point charge is diverging in the classical (Maxwell) electrodynamics. In 1930's, Born and Infeld introduced their nonlinear electrodynamics (with a Lagrangian involving higher-order corrections to the standard Maxwell Lagrangian when expanded in the field strength) in order to make the self-energy of point charges finite.

- Would it be possible that (at least some) spacetime singularities
  could be cured by a similar mechanicsm, i.e. by introducing suitable
  higher-curvature terms in the gravitational Lagrangian?

I know that such higher-curvature corrections to the Einstein-Hilbert Lagrangian appear in the string theory effective action, therefore:

- Is this the way how people expect the string theory to get rid of the
  spacetime singularities or is there some different mechanism behind
  it?

Comment: Well, I don't know for sure about what it could do to existing solutions, but consider this at least : the notion of singularity is independent of the field equations, and any metric is technically the solution of the field equation for some matter source. Therefore, the theory could still have singularities. Whether or not *realistic* solutions are singular is another matter, of course.

Comment: There are many Born-Infeld inspired modifications to gravity, and they do manage to find non-singular black hole solutions. See the overview of [Jimenez et al. (2018)](https://arxiv.org/abs/1704.03351v2). But as for string theory, I do not know, since this would be a non-perturbative effect, and those are mainly conjectured.

Comment: Check this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinite_derivative_gravity and the links in References.

Comment: @ApolloRa There is no actual proof infinite-derivative gravity prevents the formation of singularities. In particular, and quite contrary to what Anupam Mazumdar would suggest in his talks, if there is enough matter to form a horizon much larger than the mass scale of the theory, then the horizon forms either way and one has to deal with the non-perturbative black hole interior.

Comment: If you do this, do you still get a divergence-free stress-energy tensor?

Comment: @Void Thank you for the useful reference!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. The low energy limit of string theory is supergravity which does have higher derivative corrections to the Einstein-Hilbert action, but in general, it neither gets "rid" of singularities nor there is a necessity to get "rid" of them. Note that supergravity is the low energy effective field theory limit, if you wish to consider effects at the Planck scale such as singularities you will need to take into account stringy corrections. These stringy corrections are best understood in the AdS/CFT setup, where you have a dual-field theoretic description which doesn't have singularities.
2. I will talk specifically about black holes here. If you take a bunch of strings at very strong coupling and excite them to a very high energy above the Hagedorn temperature, you get the Bekenstein Hawking entropy counting and consequently you are looking at black holes. In the AdS/CFT setup you get black holes by [exciting the dual gauge theoretic degrees of freedom above the Hagedorn temperature](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0310285). There is no problem here which the existence of singularities poses.
3. As @Void mentioned in the comments, [Jimenez et al](https://arxiv.org/abs/1704.03351) discuss some possible non-singular black hole solutions in detail. Solutions such as these might or might not be realized in a string-theoretic setup.
4. There is another question which is what curing singularities buys you in quantum gravity. There are important effects like the information paradox and bags of gold paradox which don't depend on black hole singularities, but rather arise due to the existence of the horizon itself. All black hole paradoxes in quantum gravity are concerned with the interior degrees of freedom in the black hole, and can be formulated on "nice spacelike slices" which stay away from singularities everywhere. Removing singularities classically in your proposed fashion doesn't cure the problem at all here, but gives you a different problem altogether, which is basically that now you need to find an UV completion for the low energy singularity-free theory, and there is no guarantee that a stringy setup will be the UV completion for your class of higher derivative singularity free theories.

Comment: *Super*gravity is the low-energy of the *super*string. The regular string has a regular gravity (plus dilaton, whatev) infra-red.

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform Of Course!